# Searching in file using RegEx to find ID and its number with Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, full-text-search

I am fairly new to regEx and I am completely baffled by it at this point so any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Sorry if this question is around already, could not find it.
All of this is happening in Python

I am trying to do a search inside text file which has some text like:

`www.google.com, something, something : something,  [{'id': 481, 'name': 'name it needs to match'}]`

`="1000" t5:someplace="7713" t5:somethingelse="10" t5:someotherthing="10"`

it have multiple, very long lines (its a log, essentially).

What I need to do is to find a word "id" with its number by the "name" that it have inside the brackets and keep only the number (or all of it, doesn't matter) so I can put it back into the program (I am trying to create something that already exists trough API and I want to use Id of the existing thing to use it later on)

I am pretty sure I can do the slicing after I have filtered ID with its number but I am struggling to write RegEx that can find "Id" and its number by NAME.

Anyone have some insight? any advice let alone piece of code would be an immense help.
I concur that it is completely possible there is far easier solution that I am not seeing and I will be grateful if anyone can tell me said solution, I am here to learn as much as possible :)

PS: position of the "name" variable is almost always the same or at least very close to it, is there a way to use RegEx to say find the "name" and then slice everything around the "name" for approx 15-20 characters? I could then filter out the number only since I will know it is there.

Comment: Can you provide what the input and expected output? Also provide what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end I found the answer, just not by using RegEx.

this problem occurred when I was doing error handling within a script and loads data trough API.

What I needed - I was creating something with "name" or "description" (just one of each, never both) and since it was already on API I was denied, so in that case I wanted it to fall into error handling which would list all the items on API that relates to it and find the "name" or "description"  which I wanted to create in the first place, get its ID and use that on other steps which need the ID to use for its own creations.

I simply avoided using RegEx by getting a response from API in json and search trough that with for loop. I presume it is not very efficient but it does its job.

*args is a placeholder for "name" or "description" and since it is returned as a tuple of one element I simply slice the thing apart and use it to search trough the response in json format

Rather odd issue was the KeyError problem (since I get either "name" OR "description" I found it hard to detect it properly so I have gone with try and except method to pass KeyErrors and keep going until I found the one I need and pass its Id along.

```
def errorHandling(url, accessToken, args):
if args is ():
    return
lookingForThis = str(args[0])
error = ("Creation of " + lookingForThis + " at " + url + "failed. It is probably because it already exists"
                                                          ", anyhow, if it does, we found its ID and used that")
# print(error)
with open("whathaveIdone.txt", "a+") as json_file:
    json_file.write("{0}\n".format(error))
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=getHeadersWithAuthorization(accessToken), verify=False)
jsonData = json.loads(response.content)
objectID = 0
while objectID == 0:
    for p in jsonData:
        try:
            # print(p)
            if lookingForThis == p["description"]:
                objectID = p["id"]
        except KeyError:
            # print("cant find description match of " + lookingForThis + " in " + str(p))
            pass
        try:
            if lookingForThis == p["name"]:
                objectID = p["id"]
        except KeyError:
            # print("cant find name match of " + lookingForThis + " in " + str(p))
            pass
print("We managed to find and use " + lookingForThis + " at " + url + " with ID: " + str(objectID))
with open("whathaveIdone.txt", "a+") as log:
    log.write("{0} {1} {2}\n".format(url, lookingForThis, str(objectID)))
return objectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'id': (\d+),.*?'name': '([^']*)'
```

This way you'll get the ID in capture group 1 and the name in capture group 2.